# Commutativity of connecting homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq X$ a subspace and $N \hookrightarrow G \twoheadrightarrow H$ a short exact sequence of abelian groups.

We can look at the following four long exact sequences of (singular) homology groups:
$$\begin{align}
\dots \to \mathrm{H}_n(X;N) \to \mathrm{H}_n(X,A;N) \xrightarrow{\partial_{n}^{(1)}} \mathrm{H}_{n-1}(A;N) \to \dots \tag{1} \\
\dots \to \mathrm{H}_{n+1}(X;H) \to \mathrm{H}_{n+1}(X,A;H) \xrightarrow{\partial_{n+1}^{(1)}} \mathrm{H}_{n}(A;H) \to \dots \tag{2} \\
\dots \to \mathrm{H}_{n}(A;G) \to \mathrm{H}_{n}(A;H) \xrightarrow{\partial_{n}^{(2)}} \mathrm{H}_{n-1}(A;N) \to \dots \tag{3} \\
\dots \to \mathrm{H}_{n+1}(X,A;G) \to \mathrm{H}_{n+1}(X,A;H) \xrightarrow{\partial_{n+1}^{(2)}} \mathrm{H}_{n}(X,A;N) \to \dots \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Then both $\partial_{n}^{(2)} \circ \partial_{n+1}^{(1)}$ and $\partial_{n}^{(1)} \circ \partial_{n+1}^{(2)}$ are group homomorphisms from $\mathrm{H}_{n+1}(X,A;H)$ to $\mathrm{H}_{n-1}(A;N)$. Are they the same, i.e. does the equality
$$
\partial_{n}^{(2)} \circ \partial_{n+1}^{(1)} = \partial_{n}^{(1)} \circ \partial_{n+1}^{(2)}
$$
hold?

I've tried working with the explicit construction of the connecting homomorphism on a chain-complex level, but i couldn't see why this should be true. On the other hand i also couldn't come up with a counterexample...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you for your comment! Is the format is better now? What do you mean by anticommute? Does it commute up to a sign (depending on the dimension?)?